# Why I getting null Object in controller from Ajax call passing JSON object as data in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Below code is view page and call Ajax method. I need to pass address object.

```
var address = {};

address.userId = parseInt($("#userID").val());
address.addressLine1 = $("#addAddressLine1").val();
address.addressLine2 = $("#addAddressLine2").val();
address.cityId = parseInt($("#addAddressCity").val());
address.zipCode = $("#addAddressPostCode").val();
address.mobileNo = $("#addAddressPhoneNumber").val();

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("AddAddress")",
            data:JSON.stringify(address),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (responce) {
                if (responce) {
                    alert("true");
                }
                else {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("failure");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("Something went Wrong");
            }
});
```

This is the code of my controller action method. I get a `Null` value of address object when it's called from Ajax:

```
public IActionResult AddAddress([FromBody] AddressViewModel address)
{
    return Json(address != null);
}
```

This is my view model:

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("userId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("addressLine1")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("addressLine2")]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("zipCode")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("mobileNo")]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("cityId")]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
}
```

Where do I need to change my code? Do I need to change something in `StartUp.cs` ?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you check the Browser F12 Debugger --> Network tab, that you submit the request with the address object?

Comment: Build it up, start with a simple string parameter and ensure you get that, then a viewmodel with just one (string) property, then add additional properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the value of `address.userId = parseInt($("#userID").val());` and `address.cityId = parseInt($("#addAddressCity").val());`.int type cannot accept null value,if `address.userId` or `address.cityId` is null,`AddressViewModel address` will be null.You can try to use `#nullable enable` or change the value of `address.userId` or `address.cityId`.

```
#nullable enable
public class AddressViewModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("userId")]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("addressLine1")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("addressLine2")]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("zipCode")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("mobileNo")]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("cityId")]
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
}
```